# Nothing is displaying in Simulator with viewWillLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Within my GameView Controller.swift file, I removed viewDidLoad and put in viewWillLayoutSubviews because I will be using the dimensions of the device in my calculations. However, hello world SKLabelNode no longer is displayed in the simulator. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        if skView.scene != nil{
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true
            skView.showsPhysics = true
            // Create and configure the scene

            let scene = SKScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
            scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill;

            // Present Scene
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
```

Comment: Scene is generic, though I don't know about swift too well, are you sure that it is "your" scene loading, not just SKScene()?

Comment: Try `GameScene` instead of `SKScene`. BTW, you can avoid all this by setting the scale mode to `.ResizeFill` in the default view controller code.

Comment: @0x141E I tried let scene = GameScene(size:skView.bounds.size) but had no change. Another attempt: Within default view controller code, I set scaleMode to .ResizeFill and used the default GameScene.swift but the hello world was not in the center of the screen as it should be. It did run though.

Comment: @StephenJ My scene works fine because hello world is shown when i uncomment default viewDidLoad and comment my viewWillLayoutSubviews. Using default GameScene.swift when Xcode creates project.

Comment: The scene is resize after `didMoveToView` is called, so you should to use the view's frame to center the label instead of `self`.

Comment: @0x141E When I select iPhone 6 and use the frame variable instead of self, the dimensions are still listed as (1024.0,768.0). They should be reversed. That's why I wanted to use viewWillLayoutSubviews

Comment: You should use `view.frame.size` in to center the label.